# Best practice for Angular ng-repeat with nested data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following code that I admit looks pretty gross. Anyone have a suggest for cleaning it up and making it a bit more scalable without using nested tables?

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in displayData">
    <td data-ng-show="data.name">
        {{data.name}}
    </td>
    <td data-ng-show="data.cols[0]" data-ng-repeat="value in data.cols[0]"> 
        {{value}}
    </td>
    <td data-ng-show="data.cols[1]" data-ng-repeat="value in data.cols[1]"> 
        {{value}}
    </td>
    <td data-ng-show="data.cols[2]" data-ng-repeat="value in data.cols[2]"> 
        {{value}}
    </td>
    <td data-ng-show="data.cols[3]" data-ng-repeat="value in data.cols[4]"> 
        {{value}}
    </td>
    <td data-ng-show="data.cols[4]" data-ng-repeat="value in data.cols[3]"> 
        {{value}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was actually flatten data.cols to one array in the controller. Something like this:

```
var merged = [].concat.apply([], row.cols);
row.cols = merged;
$scope.displayData.push(row);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve, but I'm not entirely sure by looking at your code.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in displayData">
    <td data-ng-show="data.name">
        {{data.name}}
    </td>
    <td data-ng-show="column" data-ng-repeat="column in data.cols"> 
        {{ column.value }}
    </td>
</tr>
```